# Need to configure my JPA layer to use a TransactionManager (Spring Cloud Task + Batch register a PlatformTransactionManager unexpectedly)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I am using `Spring Cloud Task + Batch` in a project. 
I plan to use different datasources for business data and Spring audit data on the task. So I configured something like:

```
   @Bean
   public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer() {
       return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(this.singletonNotExposedSpringDatasource());
   }

   @Bean
   public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
       return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(this.singletonNotExposedSpringDatasource());
   }
```

whereas main datasource is autoconfigured through `JpaBaseConfiguration`.

The problem comes when `SimpleBatchConfiguration`+`DefaultBatchConfigurer` expose a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean, since `JpaBaseConfiguration` has a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on `PlatformTransactionManager`. Therefore `Batch's PlatformTransactionManager`, binded to the `spring.datasource` takes place.

So far, this seems to be caused because [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2788?jql=project%20%3D%20BATCH%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%204.1.2)

So I tried to emulate what `JpaBaseConfiguration` does, defining my own `PlatformTransactionManager` over my biz datasource/entityManager.

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager appTransactionManager(final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean appEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(appEntityManager.getObject());
        this.appTransactionManager = transactionManager;
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Note I have to define it with a name other than `transactionManager`, otherwise `Spring` finds 2 beans and complains (unregardless of `@Primary!`)

But now it comes the funny part. When running the tests, everything runs smooth, tests finish and `DDLs` are properly created for both business and `Batch/Task's` databases, database reads work flawlessly, but business data is not persisted in my testing database, so final `assertThats` fail when counting. If I `@Autowire` in my test `PlatformTransactionManager` or `ÈntityManager`, everything indicates they are the proper ones. But if I debug within `entityRepository.save`, and execute `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus()`, it seems the `DatasourceTransactionManager` from `Batch's` configuration is overriding, so my custom exposed `PlatformTransactionManager` is not being used.

So I guess it is not a problem of my PlatformManager being the primary, but that something is configuring my JPA layer `TransactionInterceptor` to use the non primary but `transactionManager` named bean of Batch.

I also tried with making my `@Configuration` implement TransactionManagementConfigurer and override `PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager()` but still no luck

Thus, I guess what I am asking is whether there is a way to configure the primary TransactionManager for the JPA Layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem comes when SimpleBatchConfiguration+DefaultBatchConfigurer expose a PlatformTransactionManager bean,

As you mentioned, this is indeed what was reported in [BATCH-2788](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2788). The solution we are exploring is to expose the transaction manager bean **only if** Spring Batch creates it.

In the meantime you can set the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to allow bean definition overriding and set the transaction manager you want Spring Batch to use with `BatchConfigurer#getTransactionManager`. In your case, it would be something like:

```
@Bean
public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(this.singletonNotExposedSpringDatasource()) {
        @Override
        public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
            return new MyTransactionManager();
        }
    };
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help!. But wouldnt this expose the PlatformTransactionManager anyways on SimpleBatchConfiguration?

Comment: Yes, and that's the issue currently which is due to the static annotation present in the code.. The only way to overcome this is by allowing to override bean definitions with `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` (so that the `transactionManager` exposed by Spring Batch can override any other bean named the same) and use a different name for your tx manager. Then manually configuring the tx manger you want to use in your batch config, test config, etc. A bit annoying I must admit, but we are working on it and it is planned for the upcoming releases v4.1.2 and v4.2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info!